# Fatal error: session_start() after upgrading to Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cas

I upgraded from **Codeigniter 2 to 3** and now I get this error with my **CAS library**:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: session_start() [function.session-start]: Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: C:\Windows\Temp)

Filename: CAS/Client.php

Line Number: 3588

Backtrace:
```

It has something to do with session, which I guess CI3.0 handles it differently from CI2.0.

I have the following in the **config.php**

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE
```

;

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

**NEW:**

I did a clean CI3.0.4 install and it seems like the problem is the CAS authentication library:
https://github.com/eliasdorneles/code-igniter-cas-library

It worked with CI 2.x, but not with CI3.0. If I just not load the CAS module, everything works fine with regard to the session (I have no problem setting sessions, etc). But once I load the CAS there is a problem with the line `session_start()` at the **CAS/Client.php**. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems a little odd that you are writing session files to `C:\Windows\Temp`. My guess is that the server does no have access to this folder.

Comment: How did you go with it did you try m answer?

Comment: I have updated my initial post with new info, still having the problem.

Comment: updated with new inquiries

Answer (score 8):

You have not configured your sess_save_path make sure folder also chmod 700

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = FCPATH . 'application/cache/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

The autoload session

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try code as below, it works for me

```
// before session_start();

ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files'); 

// make sure it is writeable

ini_set('session.save_path', 'c:\temp');   

session_start();
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your answer so that the code is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I've fixed it by editing libraries/Cas.php (line 55) and adding the false argument to prevent phpCAS to start the session itself
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, $cas_url['host'], $cas_url['port'], $cas_url['path'], **false**);

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. Open the phpCAS file:CAS/Client.php.
Go to about Line 3580(in "private function _renameSession").

Modifying

```
session_start();
```

to

```
if (! isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

Excuse my broken English.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Change The `sess_save_path` server section path to `/tmp`:

`$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';`